# Taking average of decimal number using bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

How can I take average of decimal values written in a file: TestFile as

```
Time to write: 0.000118000 sec

Time to write: 0.000119000 sec

Time to write: 0.000122000 sec
```

Wrong Soln:

Following prints just zero i.e. 0

```
awk '{sum+=$7}END{print sum/NR}' TestFile
```

Comment: is this file really double spaced? if so, I need to modify my answer. *now modified, below*

Comment: nah. It's singly spaced.

Comment: hm, try my solution using grep, what does it return?

Comment: Computers are sometimes not very good at measuring small intervals absent special care.  You might want to "write" 10,000 times and average that instead of averaging 10,000 individual writes (or alternatively write as many times as you can in a fixed amount of time: 10 seconds day, and divide that way).  See clock_getres() for information on finding out your system's native best resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

since you are having trouble, and seem to return zero try using this

`grep -oP "\d+\.\d+" testFile | awk -vx=0 '{x += $1} END {print x/NR}'`

this will work if the file is double spaced or not. it only prints the match of a file that has as decimal number. and sends it to awk.

the -P flag is a perl regular expression. you could do the same with -E, but `\d+` matches one or more digits, `\.` matches a period. a . has special meaning in regular expressions and need to be escaped and `\d+` matches one or more digits so put that together, `'\d+\.\d+'`, you have a decimal.

lastly, if you continue to get scientific notation you may consider printf to achieve floating point noation

`awk -vx=0 '{x += $4} END { printf ("%8.9f", x/NR) } testFile'`

you can specifiy something smaller like "%4.3f" to print only 4 numbers after a decimial, Conversely, use %e to print in scientific notation

[More using printf](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_7.html#SEC62) in `awk`

---

*old information, see above `<hr>`*

`awk -vx=0 '{x += $4} END {print x/NR}' testFile`

which outputs:

> 0.000119667

for each line append $4, which in your test file is the number, to x. At the end divide x for number of lines.

if your file is really double spaced run the following first:

`sed -i '/^$/d' testFile`  to remove blank lines. you may want to consider not editing testFile in place by removing -i and doing something like this `sed  '/^$/d' testFile > newFile`

or even combine the two files and pipe stdout from `sed` to `awk`

`sed '/^$/d' testFile | awk -vx=0 '{x += $4} END {print x/NR}'`

if this returns 0, you may have a problem with your testFile.

Comment: no, `awk` by default splits on spaces. so Time[:space:]to[:space:]write:[:space:]0.000118000[:space:]sec,time would be $1, to would be $2, write: would be $3, and so on. If it returns zero, you may have a different file then what you show. are those line breaks really in the file?

Comment: You are right. I was setting the column wrong. Ok..i got the output as: 4.4875e-05

Comment: How did you get it convert to 0.000119667?

Comment: well, do you really have only these 3 results? I'm guessing its counting the blank lines. I have updated my answer to provide two alternatives. I suggest the top answer which uses `grep`

Comment: Awesome...Can you please explain what that first command does? like what does "\d+\.\d+" and $1 in the awk statement mean?

Comment: sure, its a regular expression. I have modified my answer to explain this, and offer a solution to ensure a floating point number is returned.

Answer (score 4):

This solution will target calculation at the correct lines:

```
awk '/Time to write/ {sum+=$4; count++} END {print "avg:", sum/count}' data.txt
```